# solution to easily embed skim notes doesn't work

Tags: macos, terminal, productivity, skim

My question is directly linked to the thread [Make Skim save PDF's with embedded notes by default](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/79429/make-skim-save-pdfs-with-embedded-notes-by-default/235387#235387)

What if the proposed solution (https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/166794/180243) doesn't help? As in, I worked my way through all steps, but when I press command + s it still saves normally rather than embedded.

I just found out I lost 200 hours of carefully made annotations, and I really want to avoid that from ever happening again.

Please help.

Skim version 1.4.18 running on El Capitan

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Could you link to the answer that you followed? There are three of them - just use the share control from the answer and the edit control here to show what you tried. Also - be explicit about what "doesn't help" means. Do no annotations save? What version of skim app and OS X?

Comment: Updated my question. Thank you for the suggestions.